# Objective-C @strongify returns if self is nil

Tags: objective-c, macros, reactive-cocoa

I use weakify/strongify macros and I want to move next logic to the macros.

```
@weakify(self);
BOOL (^matchesFooOrBar)(id) = ^ BOOL (id obj){
    @strongify(self);
    if (self == nil) return; // I want to move it to the macros
```

`strongify` definition:

```
#define strongify(...) \
    rac_keywordify \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"") \
    metamacro_foreach(rac_strongify_,, __VA_ARGS__) \
    _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have spent some time to figure it out...

```
#define myStrongify(first, ...) \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wshadow\"") \
metamacro_foreach(rac_strongify_,, __VA_ARGS__) \
if (!first) { NS_VALUERETURN(NO, BOOL); } \
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
```

The usage would be like:

```
BOOL (^matchesFooOrBar)(id) = ^BOOL(id obj) {
    NSLog(@"before");
    myStrongify(obj);
    NSLog(@"after");

    // your custom logic here
    ...

    return YES;
};
```

FYI, [`NS_VALUERETURN`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NS_VALUERETURN) from apple documentation. Please feel free to test it.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add a second argument to strongify which is the default return value on null.